# Postgresql: last_analyze does not update

Tags: postgresql

I've run an analyze on a number of tables on two different databases on one of our Postgres servers.

After running the Analyze, I check "SELECT * FROM pg_stat_all_tables" and the last_update on all tables is null. The pg_stat_all_tables query takes about 10 seconds to return results. When doing the procedure on another server, the last_analyze updates as expected and the pg_stat_all_tables query shows results within milliseconds.

What could the reason for this behavior be?

Comment: I've run into this issue as well. The [stats collector](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html) generally updates these values every 500ms, but every now and then it takes a few seconds to report an `ANALYSE`, and I've never managed to figure out why. The [source](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/postmaster/pgstat.c#L2743) seems to suggest that reconnecting will flush the stats for your session, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 0):

After help from the guys on the Postgres IRC Channel, I discovered that there was an issue with the stats collector.

After a restart all is working again.